# Entity Framework ignores the inner join

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

My LINQ query joins two tables in EF 4.1, but when I look at the SQL Profiler, it just does a basic select from only one of the tables. The join is ignored. I've tried many variations on the LINQ query, but get the same result. The odd thing is that inner joins work elsewhere in my app. I can't make any sense out of it. I'm close to giving up and just calling a stored procedure but would prefer not to. Here are some examples of what I tried:

Note that SQL Profiler always gives me: `SELECT * FROM Protocols`.

```
from s in db.Staff
join p in db.Protocols on s.ID equals p.PIID
select p

from s in db.Staff
from p in db.Protocols
where p.PIID == s.ID
select p

from s in db.Staff
from p in db.Protocols
where p.PIID == s.ID && s.ID = 99
select p
```

If I do `select s` at the end, the the `Staff` table does get included, but this is obviously not what I want b/c I need the data from the protocol table.

Comment: If the inner joins in all other places in the application the problem is clearly not in the LINQ query itself.

Comment: (noob off-topic question) I'm also confused by the tag that says that Steven edited this question 12 hours ago. The question looks the same as when I entered it, so why is it saying that he editted it?

Comment: Click the "X hours ago"; it's a link to the revision history of the post.